# Why can't I connect to Flask server when hosted remotely?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, redhat

I'm writing this up because I'm running into a problem that's making me pull my hair out.

I have set up a RedHat 7 instance on AWS and I've been using it to host a Flask server as I learn the ropes. Anyways, for some reason I have been having trouble hitting the server through my browser.  I've allowed all traffic on all ports and IPs through the security mechanism on AWS and that hasn't helped.

If I run the Flask server on my local box, I can access it just fine through the browser.  If I run the Flask server on my RH7 box, I can access it as well via curl.

I have come to the conclusion that it *may* be a firewall issue, but I'm not so sure because firewalld is not installed nor is iptables.  Also, for troubleshooting purposes, I've installed and ran Apache httpd on the RH7 box and was able to hit it through my local browser.

I'm sure I'm missing something extremely simple but I just have no idea.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're not supposed to access it remotely. Though it can technically be done for debugging purposes, that's not recommended. To expose it remotely, [**deploy it properly**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/#deployment) through your apache (or any other webserver of your choosing). For more details, read through [app.run documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.run). Btw, amazon even has a page specifically for [deploying Flask with aws](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html).

Comment: Thank you!  After reading about the security issues, I'll stick to the proper deployments and most likely go with the Apache WSGI solution.  Thank you sir.